# What means this sentence and what meand "through" word in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What means this sentence and what means "through" word in this sentence? Why "are" is using in this sentence?

The Sentence: "Only once enough are through to wound him." (It's from starcraft 2 game :)).

I understand firs part "Only once enough" but don't understand "are through".

If it is possible try to explain it to me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We will lure as many of Amon's hybrid and zerg **through the gateway** as we can. Only once **enough are through** to wound him, will we overload the temple and flee.

Once enough "Amon's hybrid(s?) and zerg(s?)" have passed/walked through the gateway, we will execute our plan.